# Программа должна заменять каждый элемент стоящий на четной позиции на 0. В чем ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Примечание: надо сделать это без использования особых операторов (вручную).
Вот сам код:

```
import random

numbers = []
k = 0

for i in range(-10,10):
 i = random.randrange(-10,10)
 numbers.append(i)

print(numbers)  

for k in len(numbers):
 if k % 2 == 0:
  k = 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Нужно всего лишь немного поправить написанный Вами код, а именно цикл `for`:

```
for k in range(len(numbers)):
    if k % 2 == 0:
        numbers[k] = 0
```

Дело в том, что Вы каждую итерацию обнуляли значение `k` вместо значения элемента `numbers` c индексом `k`.

UPD. Есть ещё такая реализация, мне она нравится больше:

```
for k in range(0, len(numbers), 2):
    numbers[k] = 0
```

Comment: `numbers[::2] = 0` работает для `numpy` массивов. Для Питон-списков это похоже на `numbers[::2] = [0]* ceil(len(numbers) / 2)` (без создания временного списка)

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> for k in len(numbers):
> ```

```
for k in range(len(numbers)):
```

И ещё пара способов с созданием нового списка: http://ideone.com/0paBth

```
print([x * (i % 2) for i,x in enumerate(numbers)])
print([x if i % 2 else 0 for i,x in enumerate(numbers)])
```

Comment: x * (i % 2)  - изящно!

Comment: 1- списки создавать следует, если вы их используете в дальнейшем (не используйте списковые включения только ради побочного эффекта/side-effect) @Александр `x & 1 and x` если хочется краткости. Хотя лучше явно `x if x & 1 else 0` как в ответе уже показано, чтобы более читаемо было.

Comment: @jfs, что-то я не понял про побочные эффекты. Создаётся новый список и он выводится. Никаких побочных эффектов там нет.

Comment: Очевидно, что список у вас используется (он печатается). Мой комментарий для будущих читателей, чтобы они не использовали `[f(x) for x in L]` вместо `for x in L: f(x)`

Answer (score 4):

Вот поправил ваш код:

```
In [29]: def foo():
    ...:     import random
    ...:     numbers = []
    ...:     k = 0
    ...:     for i in range(-10,10):
    ...:         i = random.randrange(-10,10)
    ...:         numbers.append(i)
    ...:     print(numbers)
    ...:     for k in range(len(numbers)):
    ...:         if k % 2 == 0:
    ...:             numbers[k] = 0
    ...:     print(numbers)
    ...:

In [30]: foo()
[3, -4, 0, -7, 2, 2, 2, -5, -2, 8, -2, -5, 8, -1, 2, -8, 9, 3, -4, -9]
[0, -4, 0, -7, 0, 2, 0, -5, 0, 8, 0, -5, 0, -1, 0, -8, 0, 3, 0, -9]
```

Comment: Какие-то у тебя странные чётные позиции - двух ненулевых значений подряд не должно быть в результате.

Comment: @Qwertiy не вижу такого

Comment: Начало списка: `[-2, 4, 0,`

Comment: @Qwertiy ну так все правильно, у -2 индекс 0 у 4 индекс 1 а дальше четный индекс

Comment: Вообще-то 0 - это чётное число.

Comment: // Минус не мой

Comment: @Qwertiy поправил код, совсем забыл что 0 - четный :)

Answer (score 3):

Еще один вариант:

```
In [126]: numbers
Out[126]: [9, 8, 7, 6, 8, 1, 2, 1, -9, -8, -7, -10, -2, 8, -9, -8, 0, 6, 4, 7]

In [127]: numbers[::2] = [0] * len(range(0, len(numbers), 2))

In [128]: numbers
Out[128]: [0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, -8, 0, -10, 0, 8, 0, -8, 0, 6, 0, 7]
```

Если использовать Numpy, то получится коротко и быстро:

```
In [129]: import numpy as np

In [130]: a = np.array(numbers)

In [131]: a
Out[131]: array([  9,   8,   7,   6,   8,   1,   2,   1,  -9,  -8,  -7, -10,  -2,   8,  -9,  -8,   0,   6,   4,   7])
```

Решение в стиле Numpy:

```
In [132]: a[::2] = 0

In [133]: a
Out[133]: array([  0,   8,   0,   6,   0,   1,   0,   1,   0,  -8,   0, -10,   0,   8,   0,  -8,   0,   6,   0,   7])
```

**Timing** для массива из 100 миллионов элементов:

```
In [144]: a = np.random.randint(10**3, size=10**8)

In [145]: a.shape
Out[145]: (100000000,)

In [146]: %timeit a[::2] = 0
10 loops, best of 3: 42.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Жизнь меня к этому не готовила :)

Comment: @Alban, к чему вас жизнь не готовила? :)

Comment: к варианту с numpy)

Comment: @Alban, я постоянно использую Numpy из-за его скорости - я добавил  "timing" в ответ...

Comment: А в какой среде этот код пишете?

Comment: @gil9red ipython

Comment: @gil9red, как уже ответил коллега Alban это [IPython](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython)

Answer (score 2):

Можно немного изменить цикл:

```
for k in numbers:
    i = numbers.index(k)
    if i % 2 == 0:
        numbers[i] = 0
```

Или так:

```
new = [0 if (c.index(i) % 2 == 0) else i for i in numbers]
```

Comment: Эм.. Это же проверка чётности элемента, а не чётности позиции?

Comment: @Qwertiy да, читать условие полезно :) Ща поправлю

Comment: А теперь асимптотика квадратичная вместо линейной, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy Похоже на то, наверное для общего развития можно оставить, как пример получения индекса эл-та в списке, мне кажется, что если говорить о скорости обработки больших итерируемых объектов, то работа со списком по индексу в принципе не лучшая идея